# Iterate all Rows in a Column Excel without use a Loop

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a file XLS with 100.000 rows.
my code is:

```
For i = 0 to 100000
  IF NOT excelsheet.cells(i,2).value = ""
     excelsheet.cells(i,1).value = "OK"
  ELSE
     excelsheet.cells(i,1).value = "Not Good"
  End if
Next
```

It's software is very slow before have 100000 rows, it's possible use other solution?

Comment: You could do that in excel with a formula... but it all depends on the api you are using. If you are using the interopt, it will be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a way - maybe. Not without a loop, but with a faster Loop then yours.

I assume, you are working with Interop, so you can extract a cell range (gives you an array), and you can loop this array very fast, an when you are finished, set the cell range. Should be fast enough.

And no, I don´t have the code at hand, but I already did things like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different kind of loops, but you always need to loop.